# Como enviar una variable desde una función a otra dentro de un controlador en cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

Buenos días.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function sendEmail() {   

    $userid = $this->Session->read('Usuario.id');
    $sql = "SELECT profesor_id
    FROM tabla_profesores 
    WHERE teacher_id  = '" . $userid . "'";
    $logo = $this->Autoevaluacion->query($sql);
    if(!empty($logo)){
        global $teacherid;
        $teacherid = $logo[0][0]['
    }
```

Y dentro del mismo controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
private function __generarPdf(&$teacherid) {

    $logoCentro = null;
    if(file_exists(WWW_ROOT . '\logoscentros\\logo' . $teacherid . '.jpg')) {
        $logoCentro = 'logo' . $teacherid . '.jpg';
    }
```

Tengo que recoger el valor de `teacherid` dado en ese momento (y eso lo consigo) pero en ese mismo momento he de enviar ese valor a la función `__generarPdf()` que es la que genera el PDF adjunto al mail. 
Toda ayuda será bienvenida. Gracias.

PD: Son funciones que están dentro de la misma clase.

Comment: Ya que son métodos de la misma clase según entiendo,  simplemente utiliza `$this->nombreFuncion($parametros);` @Jose

Comment: Gracias @Xerif me sirvió :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llama a la función generar pdf desde la primera función, y por Dios de mi vida, utiliza el ORM de Cake, que es lo mejor que se ha inventado.

> $sql = "SELECT profesor_id
>       FROM tabla_profesores 
>       WHERE teacher_id  = '" . $userid . "'";

por esto:

```
    public function sendEmail() {   

    $userid = $this->Session->read('Usuario.id');

      $teacherId = TableRegistry::get('Profesores')->find()
              ->select('profesor_id')
              ->where([teacher_id => $userid]);

      $logo = $this->Autoevaluacion->query($sql);
      if(!empty($logo)){
        global $teacherid;
        $teacherid = $logo[0][0]['

      $this->__generarPdf($teacherId);
      //Quítale el & del parámetro a la otro función
    }
```